# Inconsistent URL paths

Tags: url, config, segments, transcribe, site-url

Having some issues with paths on my build, i get a different output using {site_url} to {path='site_index'}, {site_url} outputs the correct value but {path='site_index'} outputs the correct value with lots of backslashes on the end, really can't work out why, any ideas as to why this would happen?

{site_url} - outputs http://www.domain.co.uk/

{path='site_index'} - outputs http://www.domain.co.uk//////////////////////

We're using the standard EE config.php and the correct URL is in general confiration. We're on v2.8.1 of EE and are using Structure, really can't think what else would be causing this?

Comment: What do you have in your "Name of your site's index page" field under Admin > General Configuration

Comment: Thanks Stephen, turned out to be due to use using the module Transcribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was due to Transcribe, we needed to use {exp:transcribe:uri path="/"} paths!